# How to programatically set the text encoding for the interface of a java application?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am building an application using javafx which's interface is supposed to be in spanish. So many of the information that is read from files and displayed take accents and such. When I run the application on MACOSX it works beautifully and seemlessly.

Same happens if I run it on windows within the IDE (Netbeans 8.0, JKD 8u11).

Why, as I run the app outside the IDE on Windows 8.1, does the encoding apruptly changes ti display the text filled with replacement characters and how to fix the issue from within the code? Is it possible or is it a system variable which the user has to assume?

Also, judging by the window displayed on top of the main window, the problem only occurs when reading a text file and displaying it's content into a TextArea.

This is what i get:

[image: This]

Comment: How do you read the files? You probably use the default encoding instead of specifying the encoding with which your files have been written.

Comment: `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name+shortName+".txt")));                            
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("presentaciones/"+shortName+"/"+shortName+".txt"));
                            line = br.readLine();`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131499/changing-locale-programmatically-not-working-in-some-devices

Comment: This is an application defect. You must specify an encoding (Charset) when converting from bytes to chars or vice-versa.

Comment: You need to specificy the encoding for your InputStreamReader and get rid of the FileWriter, which uses the default encoding, and use an OutputStreamWriter with the appropriate encoding instead. Also note that if you are using Java 7+ there are easier ways to read/write files.

Comment: So the answer would be something like this and the rest just still work the same since i'm keeping the buffered readers/writers (just giving them the right encoding)??

`br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name+shortName+".txt"),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
                            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("presentaciones/"+shortName+"/"+shortName+".txt"), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));`

Comment: is "ISO-8859-1" the one I need for spanish and such??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is an application defect. You must specify an encoding (Charset)
>   when converting from bytes to chars or vice-versa. - MCDowell.
>
> You need to specificy the encoding for your InputStreamReader and get
>   rid of the FileWriter, which uses the default encoding, and use an
>   OutputStreamWriter with the appropriate encoding instead. Also note
>   that if you are using Java 7+ there are easier ways to read/write
>   files. –  assylias

**Yield the solution:**

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name+shortName+".txt"),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("presentaciones/"+shortName+"/"+shortName+".txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

**...Where UTF-8 was the encoding I actually needed as to preserve symbols such as the inverterquestionmark and accents... Thank you guys!!**