# Set locale not working on tablets

Tags: java, android, localization, tablet

I'm trying to set the locale on my application to Arabic.
I've run `setContentView()` in my Activity and in `onConfigurationChanged()`

It's working fine on the phones and changes the application locale to Arabic, 
but on tablets it's not working (the locale is not changed)

This is my code

```
 private void setLocale() {
    Locale locale = new Locale("ar","eg");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLayoutDirection(config.locale);
    }
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: What is the Android version on your tablet ?

Comment: it's Kitkat version

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it's not working" ? Locale is not changed ? Do you get any warning/error ?

Comment: Locale is not changed

Comment: Is the locale available on this device ? you can check with `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`

Comment: Also, are you trying on a real device or an emulator ? Genymotion ? Check this out  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131499/changing-locale-programmatically-not-working-in-some-devices

Comment: i'm using a real device and yes it's available